# Where did my reviews go?

Tags: bug

Just a while ago, I was reviewing posts of new users and answers, I previously reviewed 100 posts, now i  reviewed 3 posts and SO was showing I reviewed only 9 posts, then after few minutes it jumped back to hundred, now i review one post more and total reviews are 101.

My question is where did those 3 reviews go?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2009750/%C9%A2%CA%9C%CA%98%CA%82%CA%88-%CA%80%C9%9B%C9%94%CA%98%C9%B4?tab=activity&sort=reviews

Comment: I take it you are pointing to these four reviews, 1 of them is mentioned in the question and two of them are reviews after this question being asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are six different review queues, each with a separate review counter per reviewer. You have mostly been reviewing in the "First Posts" queue (~100 reviews), but you have also done a few reviews in the "Late Answers" queue.

Comment: Yes i remember two of them were Late answers.